# How do you set read/write permissions in a VS2010 windows service installer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, permissions, io, windows-services

VS2010 spits out an installer for my windows service which works, except read/write permissions are not enabled. Is there any way to have VS2010 configure the installer to give the service read/write permissions every time the service is started?

Comment: just to double check, is it even possible for a service to do IO operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions for services is determined by the account that is set to run the service. For this issue, the account was set to LOCAL SERVICE. By changing to LOCAL SYSTEM, the issue was resolved. This can be accomplished by looking at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and scrolling down to `To create the installers for your service`

> The LocalService account acts as a non-privileged user on the local computer, and presents anonymous credentials to any remote server. Use the other accounts with caution, as they run with higher privileges and increase your risk of attacks from malicious code.